# Iterating through array one at a time in react jsx

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jsx, spotify

How do I iterate one index at a time in the array 'tracks' in react jsx. I want to be able to iterate and display just one track at a time in the array, and go to the next track (index) on the click of a button that'll be labeled 'Next', also go back to previous index when clicking the button 'Previous'.

```
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state=({
        year: (props.location.state && props.location.state.year) || '',
        all_tracks: {tracks:[]},
        currentTrack: 0,
     });
  }
  onClickNext(){ //Next button
      //Nothing done here yet
  }
  onClickPrev(){ //Previous button
      //Nothing done here yet
  }
  render(){
    const {
      currentTrack,
      all_tracks: { tracks }
    } = this.state;
    return (
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { 
            this.gettingTracks() //Have tracks load immediately
        }),
       <div id = "song"> //THIS PART
              <iframe id="track" src={tracks[currentTrack]
                           ? "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/"+tracks[currentTrack].id
                           : "Song N/A"} ></iframe>
       </div>
       <div>
            <button id="nextBtn"> Next </button>
       </div>
       <div>
            <button id="prevBtn"> Previous </button>
       </div>
     );
  }
```

Here is where I populate the tracks array

```
    gettingTracks(){
    // store the current promise in case we need to abort it
    if (prev !== null) {
        prev.abort();
    }
    // store the current promise in case we need to abort it
    prev = spotifyApi.searchTracks('genre: pop year:' + this.state.year, {limit: 20, offset:1});
    prev.then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          all_tracks: { 
              tracks: data.tracks.items
            }
        })
        prev = null;
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the index of the current track as a state variable. And instead of iterating over the tracks to display them, you can just simply display the current track.

Here is a simple example,

```js
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      all_tracks: {
        tracks: []
      },
      currentTrack: 0
    };

    this.onClickNext = this.onClickNext.bind(this);
    this.onClickPrev = this.onClickPrev.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      // fetch the data  from the Spotify API and update this.state.all_tracks.tracks

  }

  onClickNext() {
    //Next button
    this.setState(prevState => {
      if (this.state.currentTrack === this.state.all_tracks.tracks.length - 1) {
        return;
      }

      return {
        ...prevState,
        currentTrack: prevState.currentTrack + 1
      };
    });
  }
  onClickPrev() {
    //Previous button
    this.setState(prevState => {
      if (this.state.currentTrack === 0) {
        return;
      }

      return { ...prevState, currentTrack: prevState.currentTrack - 1 };
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {
      currentTrack,
      all_tracks: { tracks }
    } = this.state;

    // before rendering tracks[currentTrack].name check if tracks[currentTrack] exist

    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <h3>Current Track</h3>
          <h4>
           {
             tracks[currentTrack] 
                ? tracks[currentTrack].name 
                : 'track does not exist'
           }
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="nextBtn" onClick={this.onClickNext}>
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="prevBtn" onClick={this.onClickPrev}>
            Previous
          </button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kslpl?file=/App.js:1349-1354) for demo

Comment: I understand what you did, but my array is an array of track objects from spotify and am getting this error, "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {album, artists, available_markets, disc_number, duration_ms, explicit, external_ids, external_urls, href, id, is_local, name, popularity, preview_url, track_number, type, uri}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: As seen in my original code, I'm trying to access the "name" tag inside that track object which is a string. But when I do 'tracks[currentTrack].name it'll just say it doesn't recognize the property "name"

Comment: If you can share what `all_tracks` looks like I mean the object structure for your state, I will update the answer to match with your state structure.

Comment: if `tracks[currentTrack]` is an object you can destructure the properties you want from it before rendering it.

Comment: I am trying to destructure it by doing tracks[currentTracks].name, but it is saying 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' but when I map through tracks and do {tracks.name}. I lists the track names. In the spotify API the 'name' property of the object is simply a string. 
'

Comment: And how do you want to render it?  Only the name of the current track or other details as well?

Comment: just the name of the track @subashMahapatra

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-track/

Comment: updated sandbox solution [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3rd5v?file=/App.js)

Comment: wow thank you, you are amazing, I wouldn't have gotten to that solution.

Comment: One more question, what if I wanted it to act as a circular queue. So if i clicked previous on index 1, itll go to 20th index, and likewise for 20th index going to 1. I got it to work but I get a warning that I shouldn't use setState inside of setState

Comment: I will create a sandbox with an optimal solution, but without looking at what you are trying in the code it is hard to say why you are getting the error.

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6l5mq?file=/App.js), there you go updated sandbox example with the repeated queue.

Comment: If I have to guess why the warning `shouldn't setState inside a setState` is happening, probably because you are trying to change the `currentTrack` conditionally using `setState` inside of another `setState`.

Comment: Yes that is what I was doing, I was aware of what I did wrong but wasn't sure how else to come up with the solution, thank you again

Comment: in my original post, I edited something that embeds the spotify track with the <iframe> tag, I labeled it "This part" for you to see. It actually works but on sublime a red space shows indicating some quotation issue, could you give it a look and see if that syntax is right? @subashMahapatra

Comment: I think you need to provide a `title` to the `iframe` like `title={tracks[currentTrack] ? tracks[currentTrack].name : "N/A"}`. Let me know if that solves the issue.

Comment: It doesn't solve it. The odd thing is the iframe works and the track is shown on screen, not sure why sublime is acting like theres an extra quotation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215485/discussion-between-subashmahapatra-and-surpol).